# How do you get past "snap kde-frameworks-5" issue to run Okular?

Tags: kde, snap, okular

On Ubuntu 16.04 I used the Software application to install Okular. It did not show up in the dash. So I went to a terminal to start it. I got this messsage:

```
You need to connect this snap to the kde-frameworks-5 snap.

You can do this with those commands:
snap install kde-frameworks-5
snap connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-slot
```

I ran the "snap install kde-frameworks-5" command and it appears to have worked. If I re-run it (due to Okular continuing to tell me to) I get:

```
snap "kde-frameworks-5" is already installed, see "snap refresh
--help"
```

Running the "snap connect ..." command does not give a similar message. It appears to toggle it's output slightly. One time:

```
[/] Connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug to kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-sl
[-] Connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug to kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-sl
[\] Connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug to kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-sl
[|] Connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug to kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-sl
```

another:

```
[/] Connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug to kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-sl
[-] Connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug to kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-sl
[\] Connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug to kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-sl
```

But trying to start Okular just keeps giving me the original message that I need to download and connect.

Comment: Just to register, more than a year after this question, I had the same problem using Ubuntu 18.04! =/ (Reinstalling Okular's snap brings it back to life!)

Answer (score 1):

You should run both commend with root user or `sudo`

```
sudo snap install kde-frameworks-5
sudo snap connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-slot
```

I got same issue that running `okular` asking me to do that. I checked `snap interfaces | grep okular` and it seems good:

```
:home                                   okular
:network                                okular
:network-bind                           core,okular
:opengl                                 okular
:pulseaudio                             okular
:unity7                                 okular
:x11                                    okular
kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-slot  okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug
okular:session-dbus-interface
```

So I reinstalled `okular` left `kde-frameworks-5` installed. Now it works fine:

```
sudo snap remove okular
sudo snap install okular
```

It seems to me a bug, if you are interested please report it against `snapd` package.