# Why can't I get gnome-system-monitor snap to work?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, snap, system-monitor

I was running the GNOME system monitor when it unexpected disappeared with no explanation, i.e. it seemingly quit on its own. I tried to run it again and nothing happened, so I ran it from the command line and got an error telling me I need to run a couple of commands:

```
$ gnome-system-monitor 
You need to connect this snap to the gnome platform snap.

You can do this with those commands:
snap install gnome-3-28-1804
snap connect gnome-system-monitor:gnome-3-28-1804 gnome-3-28-1804
```

I did so, but when I try to run it again I get an error telling me I need to run the two exact commands I just ran!

```
$ snap install gnome-3-28-1804
$ snap connect gnome-system-monitor:gnome-3-28-1804 gnome-3-28-1804
$ gnome-system-monitor 
You need to connect this snap to the gnome platform snap.

You can do this with those commands:
snap install gnome-3-28-1804
snap connect gnome-system-monitor:gnome-3-28-1804 gnome-3-28-1804
```

What's going on here?!  Why isn't this working when I just did what it told me to do?

P.S. Please don't ask me to uninstall the snap and install the non-snap version.  I want to understand why the snap version isn't working and how to make it work.

Comment: If it's possible, please provide the actual bits of "got an error telling me I need to run a couple of commands." So what exactly was the error? And are the commands the ones you've listed? What about the other snaps on your system, how do they work?

Comment: From my brief experience with snaps, if they're installed with `sudo snap install ...`, the connection to other stuff is automatic. Have you run `snap refresh`?

Comment: @DKBose The error was the exact same thing displayed when I ran gnome-system-monitor.  I'll update to reflect that.  I didn't install these snaps, they were factory installed.   `snap refresh` said `All snaps up to date.` but didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, I remember that about three snaps came installed with Ubuntu 18.04. Are the others working?

Comment: Similar situation here: https://askubuntu.com/q/906086/248158. Unfortunately, they took the reinstall route! See https://askubuntu.com/q/1087032/248158 as well.

Comment: @DKBose Not sure if I have interacted with any other snaps.  But I did a reboot and strangely it's working again now.  I noticed that snaps seem to be squashfs mounts, maybe something got corrupted?

Comment: Rebooting for the win! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0